# AVQueuePlayer unable to use setVolume

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

i get the error
No visible @interface for 'AVQueuePlayer' declares the selector 'setVolume:'

when trying to setVolume of an AVQueuePlayer i created. Why is this happening? Isn't AVQueuePlayer a subclass of AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 0):

`AVQueuePlayer` is a subclass of `AVPlayer` not a subclass of `AVAudioPlayer`.

`AVPlayer` doesn't have a `setVolume` method, hence the error.